# problem with DTedit in shiny: adding new row is pass to successive data.frame when combined with selectInput and Observe event. How can I avoid this?

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I'm developing an app for users to review some data. The goal is to edit, delete, and add new data according to their knowledge. I have two `selecInput`. The first one select a group. The second one, select a unit from that group (see dummy data). When someone tries to add a new row to the data a1, for example, and then change to a2 in the second `selecInput`, `dtedit` will add that row into the a2 data.frame.

I've tried defining the `dtedit` data frame from outside the `observeEvent` environment but it is the same. Can someone help me solving this? Thanks. Here is the code to replicate my problem:

```
library(shiny)
library(DTedit)
df1 <-  data.frame(A = c('a1', 'a2', 'a3'), 
                   B = c('b1', 'b2', 'b3'), 
                   C = c('c1', 'c2', 'c3'))

df2 <- list(a1=data.frame(Symbol = factor(rep('a1', 3), levels = 'a1'), 
                         Class = factor(c('Good', 'Bad', 'Neutral'), levels =c('Good', 'Bad', 'Neutral')), 
                         Status = factor(c('old', 'old', 'old'), levels = c('old', 'new'))), 
            a2 = data.frame(Symbol = factor(rep('a2', 3), levels = 'a2'), 
                            Class = factor(c('Good', 'Bad', 'Neutral'), levels =c('Good', 'Bad', 'Neutral')), 
                            Status = factor(c('old', 'old', 'old'), levels = c('old', 'new'))), 
            a3 = data.frame(Symbol = factor(rep('a3', 3), levels = 'a3'), 
                            Class = factor(c('Good', 'Bad', 'Neutral'), levels =c('Good', 'Bad', 'Neutral')), 

                            Status = factor(c('old', 'old', 'old'), levels = c('old', 'new'))),
            b1 =data.frame(Symbol = factor(), Class = factor(), Status = factor()), 
            b2 =data.frame(Symbol = factor(), Class = factor(), Status = factor()), 
            b3=data.frame(Symbol = factor(), Class = factor(), Status = factor()), 

            c1=data.frame(Symbol = factor(), Class = factor(), Status = factor()),
            c2 =data.frame(Symbol = factor(), Class = factor(), Status = factor()),
            c3=data.frame(Symbol = factor(), Class = factor(), Status = factor()))

ui <-  fluidPage(

  fluidRow(
    column(4, 
           selectInput(inputId = 'condition1', 
                       'First Condition', 
                       choices = c('A', 'B', 'C')),
           uiOutput("conditionalTab")),
    column(6,
           uiOutput('tableFiltered'))
    )
  )

server <- function(input, output, session){
  output$conditionalTab <- renderUI({
    selectInput("User", "Second condition",
                choices = df1[[input$condition1]], 
                selected = "")
  })

  observeEvent(input$User, {
    df_edit <- df2[[input$User]]

    DTedit::dtedit(input, output, name = 'tableFiltered', 
                  thedata = df_edit

                  )


  })



}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```r
library(shiny)
library(DTedit)
df1 <- data.frame(
  A = c("a1", "a2", "a3"),
  B = c("b1", "b2", "b3"),
  C = c("c1", "c2", "c3"),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

prototype_dataframe <-
  data.frame(
    Symbol = factor(levels = c("alpha", "beta", "gamma")),
    Class = factor(levels = c(1, 2, 3)),
    Status = factor(levels = c("Active", "Inactive", "Unknown"))
    )

df2 <- list(
  a1 = data.frame(
    Symbol = factor(rep("a1", 3), levels = "a1"),
    Class = factor(c("Good", "Bad", "Neutral"), levels = c("Good", "Bad", "Neutral")),
    Status = factor(c("old", "old", "old"), levels = c("old", "new"))
  ),
  a2 = data.frame(
    Symbol = factor(rep("a2", 3), levels = "a2"),
    Class = factor(c("Good", "Bad", "Neutral"), levels = c("Good", "Bad", "Neutral")),
    Status = factor(c("old", "old", "old"), levels = c("old", "new"))
  ),
  a3 = data.frame(
    Symbol = factor(rep("a3", 3), levels = "a3"),
    Class = factor(c("Good", "Bad", "Neutral"), levels = c("Good", "Bad", "Neutral")),

    Status = factor(c("old", "old", "old"), levels = c("old", "new"))
  ),
  b1 = prototype_dataframe,
  b2 = prototype_dataframe,
  b3 = prototype_dataframe,

  c1 = prototype_dataframe,
  c2 = prototype_dataframe,
  c3 = prototype_dataframe
)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(
      4,
      selectInput(
        inputId = "condition1",
        "First Condition",
        choices = c("A", "B", "C")
      ),
      uiOutput("conditionalTab")
    ),
    column(
      6,
      uiOutput("tableFiltered")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$conditionalTab <- renderUI({
    selectInput("User", "Second condition",
      choices = df1[[input$condition1]],
      selected = ""
    )
  })

  dt_results <- list() # get ready to be filled!
  lapply(
    # create a dtedit and observeEvent for each dataframe
    names(df2),
    # go through all the 'names' of df2 dataframes
    function(i) {
      dt_results[[i]] <- DTedit::dtedit(
        input, output,
        name = paste0("tableFiltered", i),
        # e.g. 'tableFiltereda1', 'tableFiltereda2' ...
        thedata = df2[[i]]
      )
      observeEvent(dt_results[[i]]$thedata, ignoreInit = TRUE, {
        # store results back into df2
        # some 'persistence' (though not stored in a file)
        df2[[i]] <<- dt_results[[i]]$thedata
      })
    }
  )

  observeEvent(input$User, priority = 0, {
    output$tableFiltered <- renderUI({
      uiOutput(paste0("tableFiltered", input$User))
    })
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Thanks Baltazar.

I needed to re-write the code to actually get it running in the expected way. The original code gave no useful options for tables B and C and did not write back results to `df2`, which made it harder to see the problem you saw.

Eventually it appears that attempting to changes in `input$User` significantly confuses `dtedit`, each re-definition of `output$tableFiltered` reads some of the previous inputs (e.g. adding a row of data) resulting in extraneous added rows.

Strangely, this happened even when I gave separate names to each of the `dtedit` objects (with `paste0("tableFiltered", input$User)`), resulting in separately named `input`s to each of the `dtedit` objects. I suspect `shiny` might be at fault, here...

But the problem does *not* happen when all the separate `dtedit` objects are defined (or, in an alternative solution, displayed!) ahead of time, which is what I did in the below solution with `lapply`, following the example in [Dynamic UI elements in Shiny, by Statworx (also on R-bloggers)](https://www.statworx.com/de/blog/dynamic-ui-elements-in-shiny/).

The solution below does require more CPU time to establish, and may be impractical if hundreds of objects need to be created, or the dataframe `df2` changes dynamically.

This solutions works both with [`jbryer/dtedit`](https://github.com/jbryer/DTedit) and also [an extended version of dtedit `DavidPatShuiFong/dtedit`](https://github.com/jbryer/DTedit/pull/5).